# Make responsive CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make a responsive grid that takes up the entire width of the screen and without any gaps between each element.

Each elements have to be a square.

I want four elements per line on large screens and one element per line on smartphones.

```css
#work {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.post {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="work">
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
```

**Image of the result:**

[Image of the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw4j4.png)

Perfect in large screen but when i reduce the size of my window, elements don't go under each other but still in place and i can scroll in X.

I've tried many solutions i could have found on the internet but no one worked.

Excuse me in advance for any mistakes I may have, I am a beginner in HTML & CSS

Comment: you can use the css media rule https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
set the width of post elements to 100% when a specific min-width get reached
`@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .post {
        width: 100%;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `@media` role by setting the `grid-template-columns` to 1

```css
#work {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.post {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
#work { 

  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}
.post {
 width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="work">
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with flexbox and set the flex-wrap to wrap.

```css
#work {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="work">
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#work {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 20rem);
  gap: 2rem;
}

.post {
  width: 480px;
  height: 480px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: red;
}
```

Large Screen

[image]

Mobile
[image]

I've added a red background just for demonstration and you can tweak the sizes. But this should help you achieve what you are looking to do?